# SQL Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting this error and I can’t figure out why. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘(((plot.[annual charge]) Like "*"))
>   UPDATE Plot SET Plot . [annual charge] = IIF([annual charge]<,[annual charge]+[annual charge]*15/100,[annual charge]*10/100);

Code:

```
SELECT plot.[annual charge]
FROM (
    (
        member INNER JOIN plot ON (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
            AND (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
            AND (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
        ) INNER JOIN produce ON plot.[plot number] = produce.[plot number]
    )
INNER JOIN vegetables ON produce.[vegtable name] = vegetables.[vegetable name]WHERE (((plot.[annual charge]) LIKE "*"))UPDATE Plot
SET Plot.[annual charge] = IIF([annual charge] <, [annual charge] + [annual charge] * 15 / 100, [annual charge] * 10 / 100);
```

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable, but did not add any white spaces to the query. It seems you are missing white spaces before `WHERE` and `UPDATE`. Could that be the reason for this error?

Comment: @SergeyS. Your edit changed the query! It's possbile that you thereby removed the reason for the error. Please never change code when editing questions.

Comment: Your `IIF()` function call seems wrong.  You have: `IIF([annual charge] <, [annual charge]...` (ellipsis mine).  You need something besides a comma following that first `[annual charge]`.  What do you want to compare it to?

Comment: I think the whole SQL is wrong. Here are 2 separate SQLs - SELECT and UPDATE. UPDATE for two tables has different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE (
        (
            member INNER JOIN plot ON (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
                AND (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
                AND (member.[member number] = plot.[member table])
            ) INNER JOIN produce ON plot.[plot number] = produce.[plot number]
        )
INNER JOIN vegetables ON produce.[vegtable name] = vegetables.[vegetable name]
WHERE (((plot.[annual charge]) LIKE "*"))
SET Plot.[annual charge] = IIF([annual charge] < 1000000, [annual charge] + [annual charge] * 15 / 100, [annual charge] * 10 / 100);
```

Replace 1000000 by desired number

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check your parenthesis. there is an opening brace with no closing brace if i am not mistaken. that could be the cause of your error.